# Why is $2r'dr' = (2r - 2acos\theta)dr$ - Law of Cosines relationship

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

$r' = \sqrt{r^2 + a^2 - 2arcos\theta}$

Why, then, is $2r'dr' = (2r - 2acos\theta)dr$

[image]

Note - cursive $r$ in the diagram is written as $r'$ above.

Comment: Square the formula & differentiate (assume $a$ & $\theta$ remain constant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r' = \sqrt{r^2 + a^2 - 2arcos\theta}=(r^2 + a^2 - 2arcos\theta)^{1/2}$$

$$dr'=\frac{1}{2}(r^2 + a^2 - 2arcos\theta)^{-1/2}(2r-2a\cos\theta)dr$$

$$dr'=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + a^2 - 2arcos\theta}}(2r-2a\cos\theta)dr$$

$$dr'=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{r'}(2r-2a\cos\theta)dr$$

$$2r'dr'=(2r-2a\cos\theta)dr$$